# Deformation between two quadrilaterals

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

Cross posting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776046/computing-the-transformation-matrix-that-took-place-between-two-quadrilaterals?noredirect=1#comment72667463_42776046) SO post, as I realized this would be a more apt place to put it.

I have two sets of 4 vertices that make a quadrilateral in 2D coordinate space. These 4 vertices can be scaled, rotated, translated, and skewed in any way. For example:

[image]

With my limited knowledge of linear algebra I'm assuming that a "transformation matrix" can be used to create a mapping between vertices in State 1 and vertices in State 2.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I have several quadrilaterals in one state (possibly different quads), that all undergo some uniform transformation (camera movement) to get to state 2. I'm assuming that if I compute the transformation from one quad in state 1 to state 2, I can apply the same transformation to all quads in state 1.